# Return a List<string> with a linq compiled query

Tags: c#, linq, linq.compiledquery

I'm creating a compiled linq to sql query based on the tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/compiled-queries-in-linq/) and I'm trying to figure out how to return the results as a list so I can use the results in my code. Currently it is the default IEnumerable and I get the error that it can't be enumerated twice.

```
public static Func<OoplesDBDataContext, string, IEnumerable<string>> GetValidSymbols
    {
        get
        {
            Func<OoplesDBDataContext, string, IEnumerable<string>> func =
                CompiledQuery.Compile<OoplesDBDataContext, string, IEnumerable<string>>
                ((OoplesDBDataContext context, string market) =>
                from c in context.Symbols
                where c.Market == market && c.isActive == true && c.isUnderReview == false
                select c.Symbol1);
            return func;
        }
    }

public static List<string> getStockSymbols(string market)
    {
        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (OoplesDBDataContext context = new OoplesDBDataContext())
            {
                context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
                var query = QueriesUtility.GetValidSymbols(context, market);

                return query.ToList(); // breaks here with the error
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Details on the error?

Comment: You need update your code, In your code `GetValidSymbols` return a delegate, and you're call `ToList()` at a delegate

Comment: Based on the _detailed_ description of the problem and the error all I can say is you need to fix the error.

Comment: Sorry I had to step away for a little bit. I am very confused by the issue because for the first 3 times I got the error about not being able to enumerate twice but then without changing anything at all it suddenly started working. I'm also getting strange fatal exceptions when running visual studio so I believe it is related somehow